# How to tell jquery mobile not to do its thing until I tell it to

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a site with many 'pages', and thus the jqm pageinit phase is lengthy (4 seconds).

Ideally I would like to tell jqm to not touch a 'page' until that page is navigated to for the first time. In other words, if I have a *data-role = 'page'* with a *data-role = 'button'* on it, I want jqm to **not** mess with that 'button' until the page is actually visited.

This of course also brings up the problem: once I am ready for jqm to process all jqm-elements on a  'page', how do I do that?

---

NOTE:
*It seems that most answers to this question suggest data-role = 'none', but that is a different issue ... I want my data-role = 'something', but yet not to be processed until called for.*

Comment: From a quick scan of the documentation, it sounds like this is what `data-enhance='false'` does. Quoting: *Any DOM elements inside a data-enhance="false" container, save for data-role="page|dialog" elements, will be ignored during initial enhancement...*

Comment: Jonathan, that works, although it was necessary to accompany that with `jQuery(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){ jQuery.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true; });  `

........................... 
Now I am trying to process that ignored content when the 'page' is navigated to by the user. Currently I am setting `jQuery( "a_page_selector" ).on( 'pageinit'  , function( e ,o ){jQuery( e.target ).trigger( "create" ) ;})`, but it does not do it.

Comment: here is the reason why my `my_page.trigger( "create" )` did not work: because the `my_page.content.attribute[ data-enhance ]` was still set to false, so before calling the .trigger('create'), you must toggle the data-enhance to true.